# Non repeatable fields in models

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a directive in models.py that allows me to have a value not repeated in a field? I'm making a table of people and I need the email field not to be repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass [**`unique=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) to that field.

For example:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```

As specified in the documentation:

> **`Field.unique`**
>
> If `True`, this field must be **unique throughout the table**.
>
> This is enforced at the **database level** and by **model
>   validation**. If you try to **save a model with a duplicate value** in
>   a unique field, a `django.db.IntegrityError` will be raised by the
>   model’s `save()` method.
>
> This option is valid on all field types except `ManyToManyField` and
>   `OneToOneField`.
>
> Note that when unique is True, you don’t need to specify `db_index`,
>   because unique implies the creation of an index.

So here for every two different `MyModel` objects, we know that their `email` field will contain a *different* value.